# change HtmlSelectOneMenu display value based on SelectItem information

Tags: jsf-2

Hi I have a problem about dynamically displaying the value of a HtmlSelectOneMenu. Below is a small application that describes my problem.

I have a list of cars `List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>()` in my backing bean.

Car is a abstract class and `Toyota` and `Ford` extends `Car`.

Now I need to display different message in the selectonemenu based on the class type. If it is Toyota then I would display something else. Maybe its clearer for the codes to tell the story.

Backing Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="myBean")
@SessionScoped
public class MyCarBackingBean implements PhaseListener {

    private List<Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    private HtmlSelectOneMenu hsom;
    Car myCar;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        carList.add(new Ford());
        carList.add(new Toyota());
    }


    @Override
    public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    //hsom becomes null here. Im pretty sure the setHsom was called before and the variable was set.
    if(hsom != null) {
        switch((Integer)hsom.getValue()){
            case 1: hsom.setValue("This is a Ford car"); break;
            case 2: hsom.setValue("This is a Toyota car"); 
        }
    }


    //The rest of the world...
}
```

And i bind the selectonemenu to the component in my page:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu binding="#{myBean.hsom}">
       <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.carList}" var="car" itemValue="#{car.id}" itemLabel="#{car.id}" />
       </h:selectOneMenu>
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{myBean.mySubmit()}"/>
</h:form>
```

And finally the model classes:

```
public abstract class Car {

    protected int id;
    //Getters and Setters

}

public class Toyota extends Car {

    public Toyota(){
        this.id = 2; //in case of ford car, id is 1.
    }

}
```

And I'm thinking using a phase listener to change the display, cos I read some posts saying that it is bad to change the getters and setters and put business logic in them. Nor do I want to wrap those cars in other objects and make use of `itemLabel` and `itemValue`.

But when I was debugging it I found that `hsom` is `null` when the execution reaches `beforePhase` but it is not null in the rest part of the code.

So my questions are : is it a good way to use a phase listener for this? And why is the component object null in `beforePhase`?

Comment: OK turns out that a phaselistener and a managedbean are different things...and if I am to change the value of the component before rendering, I should instead use `<f:event>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a different attribute (say `description`) to your class. Implement it as you like, and refer to it in the `selectItems` tag. V.g.

```
<f:selectItems value="#{myBean.carList}" var="car" itemValue="#{car.id}" itemLabel="#{car.description}" />
```

Alternatively, replace `myBean.carList` with a method that returns a `List<SelectItem>`, and create the `selectItems` as you wish.

As a rule of thumb, try to keep the .xhtml as "logic-free" as possible.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. The problem is that in my real application those classes were given to me and i am not able to change them. I also thought about converting them to other objects that are jsf friendly like u described but the convertion in my real case is heavy weight and the list may grow very large in the future as well.

Comment: It sounds good to keep the configuration files logic free. Thanks a lot for the 'rule of thumb' xD

Comment: Instead a conversion (or copy) into another object, what about building a wrapper? The wrapper does not copy the values but references the original object, and can add a few property in its own.

Comment: HiSjuan. I think I will just use the Wrappers to save the trouble:-)  Thank you very much xD

Comment: If the wrapper is only for selects, maybe it is worth directly using [`selectItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html)

Comment: Nice suggestion. Looks perfect for wrappers :)